# Junit testing dependent methods

Tags: java, junit

I'm having trouble with Junit testing, and can find little info online.

Firstly, I want to test 2 methods,

1.`setTable(int r, int c, String s)`

2.`getTableString()`.

I managed to test the first one, but the second one requires that the table be already built (the table being a `private static char[][]` with a getter, and is built by the first method).

How do I go about testing this second method? I thought of doing this:

```
    public void testGetTableString() {

        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        test.setTable(5, 4, "string");
        String toTest = test.getTableString();
        assertEquals("expected result", toTest);
    }
```

This however doesn't seem right since it's dependent on `setTable` working.

I also thought of initializing `test.setTable(5,4,"string")` in the setUp() method, but that would mean that I'd have to change the parameters for `setTable` in the `setUp()` method each time and not be able to track my tests; plus it would `setUp()` for my first method too, which I don't want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your first test is just fine. It is difficult to get completely away from these kinds of dependencies. p.s. Why is the table `static`?

Comment: Thanks, I rechecked and removed it. There was no real reason for it to be `static`

Comment: You should aim to test the entire behaviour of your class - that is, that it can store something and retrieve it later.  When you decide what test cases to include in the test for a class, don't be surprised if you end up with test cases that span multiple methods.  This is fine and normal.  It is incorrect to test each method individually, without thinking of the overall behavioural requirements of the class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE: *This however doesn't seem right since it's dependent on setTable working.*

What you have done is perfectly appropriate.  If getTableString() is the method-under-test, then the best way to isolate it is to setup the necessary pre-conditions.  Also, by putting the setTable call right in this test method, you have isolated these conditions to this one test (as opposed to putting the call in setup() which will be seen by all test methods).

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have two methods (to test) doesn't mean there has to be two methods to test them. You can club that in a single junit test.

Since they are related, you cant really say `setXY` works unless you verify with `getXY`